# Problem using the Find References (Inno Setup) feature in Visual & Installer

Tags: visual-and-installer

Let us say that I want to find all instances of where `AddFileForDownload` in used in my script to Visual & Installer in Visual Studio.

When I do it to usual way:

[image: Find All]

And it produces results as I expect:

[image: Find All Results]

But when I try to use the bespoke feature in Visual & Installer:

[image: Find VI]

I end up with this:

[image: Find VI pane]

If I drag the pane out it then looks like this:

[image: Find VI pane dragged]

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2019 (16.6.2)
- Visual & Installer (1.0.4.8)

Comment: What happens when you try to show the window only? in main Visua Studio's menu: View -> Othew windows -> Find References (Inno Setup)

Comment: @Slappy Exactly the same. Since it is docked, it tries to re-display it in the docked area, and goes funny.

Comment: @Slappy I am using Visual Assist on my computer and "ResOrg". They are the only other extensions.

Comment: @Slappy Do you think this is something you will be ablle to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in VS 2019 which is caused by **blocking any extension from synchronously autoloading since 16.1**, see: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/updates-to-synchronous-autoload-of-extensions-in-visual-studio-2019/

In V&I this applies to Suggestions (Light Bulb actions - Add File(s) / Add Folder into script) and the References window. Both must be reworked/fixed for VS 2019.

The Suggestions are already done and we are currently working on the References window.

Both will be ready in next V&I release.

Update 27-11-2020: The transparent (blank) controls in References windows are caused by changes in .net DPI awareness: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2019/06/11/blank-tool-windows-resharper-visual-studio-2019-net-framework-4-8-per-monitor-dpi-awareness/

**Temporary solution** is to uncheck *Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities* via Tools | Options, then Environment | General.

[image]

Update 2020-11-30: Today we have **released an updated version** of this tool where **we have fixed this issue** (it is necessary to reinstall the extension in Visual Studio 2019).

See the details and get latest version from official website: http://visual-installer.com/changelog.html#10410

Comment: Great. Shall we leave this question open until it is resolved?